# FFmpeg combine Stream Loop and Filter into one command

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently running two FFmpeg commends:

[1] [Looping a video for the entire duration of an audio file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55841289/266435)

```bash
ffmpeg  -stream_loop -1 -i 1min-loop.mp4 -i 2min-song.mp3 -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -y looped-video.mp4
```

[2] Taking the resulting file add overlaying image files.

```bash
ffmpeg -i looped-video.mp4 -i overlay.png -i art.jpeg -filter_complex "\
  [2:v]scale=400:400[resized-artwork];\
  [0][resized-artwork]overlay=100:100[vid-and-artwork];\
  [vid-and-artwork][1:v]overlay=0:0" final-video.mp4
```

Is it possible to combine these into one command? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use the main input with stream loop, and add -shortest

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i 1min-loop.mp4 -i overlay.png -i art.jpeg \
-i 2min-song.mp3 -filter_complex "\
  [2:v]scale=400:400[resized-artwork];\
  [0][resized-artwork]overlay=100:100[vid-and-artwork];\
  [vid-and-artwork][1:v]overlay=0:0[v]" \
  -map [v] -map 3:a -shortest final-video.mp4
```

Use ffmpeg v5.0 or newer.